# Find out last Option value in Drop down list Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

How can we select the "Last" Option value in Drop down list

find out the html code, this Drop down box items generate dynamically based on the record size in Grid

```
<select id="CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize" onchange="return ddlPageChange();"name="ctl00$CPHRegContent$ddlPageSize">
<option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

some time it may have 3 items

```
<select id="CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize" onchange="return ddlPageChange();" name="ctl00$CPHRegContent$ddlPageSize">
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

each execution of my code, it should be select the last option item in that drop down list,
let me know how can we proceed for this situation

Comment: with jquery u  can get it this way `$('#CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize option:last').val();`

Comment: thanks but i want web driver with Java

Comment: if your writing a jsp or jsf page, then u can call this jquery on change event of the drop down event handler which is already attached with element.

Comment: @Prabu Then why to tag question with jQuery? PS: You can Javascript/jQuery with Slenium Java binding

Answer (score 2):

this is the code to select the last items in Drop down list

```
Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//*[@id='CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize']")));
    int selectOptions = selectBox.getOptions().size();
    selectBox.selectByIndex(selectOptions - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

your jquery

```
alert($('#CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize > option:last').val());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/6xU2v/)

Comment: OP wants to achieve it through Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery that dreamweiver provided to you.

To work with jquery in selenium webdriver (java) you have to use option by.cssSelector,
like this:

```
WebElement last = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('#CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize > option:last'));
```

P.S. I dont have 50 reputation to comment, so posted this as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery this XPath should work:

```
//select[@id='CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize']/option[last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try this though it is some what same like above's :

```
public void SelectDropDown()
{
   WebElement selectDropDown =driver.findElement(By.id("CPHRegContent_ddlPageSize"));
   List<WebElement> option=selectDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
   ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<option.size();i++)
   {
       list.add(option.get(i).getText().trim());
   }

   Collections.reverse(list);

   String lastOption=list.get(0);

   new Select(selectDropDown).selectByVisibleText(lastOption);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select selectBox = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> webElementList = selectBox.getOptions();

System.out.println("Available Options Size " + webElementList.size());

if(webElementList.size()>0)         
selectBox.selectByIndex(webElementList.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Printing last option from dropdown.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Dropdown')]")).click();
Select drpdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='dropdown']")));
    List<WebElement> DrpdwnOptions = drpdown.getOptions();
    int OptionsCount = DrpdwnOptions.size();
    
    for(int i =(OptionsCount-1); i<OptionsCount; i++) 
    
        {
        
            System.out.println("Print Options :" +DrpdwnOptions.get(i).getText());
        }
```